# Chamar método pelo action do form

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

É possível chamar um método via post pelo action do form? Como?

```
<?php  

class Produto {

public function insere() {
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $descricao = $_POST['descricao'];
    $preco = $_POST['preco'];
    $conexao = new Database();
    $produto = new Produto();
    $produto->setNome($nome);
    $produto->setPreco($preco);
    $produto->setDescricao($descricao);
    $produtoDao = new ProdutoDao();
    $produtoDao->adiciona($conexao, $produto);
}
}
```

---

```
<form method="post" action=" ">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Nome</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nome">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
       <label>Descrição</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="descricao">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
       <label>Preço</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="preco">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Adicionar</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não, não é possivel chamar um determinado metodo pela `action` do formulário, pelo menos não diretamente, a `action` é para aceder a um serviço (url) no seu caso suponho que será um script php:

Nota que se `action` for para decorrer no mesmo script/ficheiro onde decorre a submição do formulário o [mais recomendado é nem definir uma action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131781/is-it-a-good-practice-to-use-an-empty-url-for-a-html-forms-action-attribute-a).

**1.** Exemplo de como fazer no seu caso, caso o script que processa os dados enviados seja outro ficheiro:

```
<form method="post" action="Produto.php">
   ...
</form>
```

Produto.php

```
class Produto {

    public function insere($dados) {
        $nome = $dados['nome'];
        $descricao = $dados['descricao'];
        $preco = $dados['preco'];
        ...
    }
}
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') { // aqui é onde vai decorrer a chamada se houver um *request* POST
    $product = new Produto;
    $product->insere($_POST);
}
```

**2.** Caso o script seja no mesmo serviço (url) de onde são enviados os dados (submição do formulário) pode:

```
<?php
class Produto {
    public function insere($dados) {
        $nome = $dados['nome'];
        $descricao = $dados['descricao'];
        $preco = $dados['preco'];
        ...
    }
}
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') { // aqui é onde vai decorrer a chamada se houver um *request* POST
    $product = new Produto;
    $product->insere($_POST);
}
?>
<form method="post">
    ...
</form>
```

**3.** Para o caso de ter dois formulários por exemplo, um para editar, outro para adicionar pode fazer:

```
<form method="post" action="Produto.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="method" value="insere">
    ...
</form>

<form method="post" action="Produto.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="method" value="edita">
    ...
</form>
```

Produto.php

```
class Produto {

    public function insere($dados) {
        $nome = $dados['nome'];
        $descricao = $dados['descricao'];
        $preco = $dados['preco'];
        ...
    }
    public function edita($dados) {
        ...
    }
}
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && isset($_POST['method'])) { // aqui é onde vai decorrer a chamada se houver um *request* POST
    $method = $_POST['method'];
    if(method_exists('Produto', $method)) {
        $product = new Produto;
        $product->$method($_POST);
    }
    else {
        echo 'Metodo incorreto';
    }
}
```

Comment: Na verdade são arquivos diferentes. Com arquivos diferentes não é possível então?

Comment: Era isso mesmo. Deu certo, era exatamente o que eu precisava, obrigado.